# Can Javascript Class methods still be considered "pure", if they call other "pure" class methods?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, functional-programming, pure-function

Consider

```js
class Service {
    methodA(input: string[]): number {
        const resB = this.methodB(input);
        return resB * 2;
    }
    methodB(input: string[]): number {
        return input.length;
    }
}
```

If MethodB is a pure function, can MethodA also be considered a pure function?

What about the case, when MethodB is a pure function from an injected class?

```js
class Service {
    constructor(helper:Helper){}
    methodA(input: string[]): number {
        const resB = this.helper.methodB(input);
        return resB * 2;
    }
}
```

In both cases I argued yes in my team, because both cases no side effects takes place and the input>output is deterministic.

On the other side, let alone the the fact, that MethodA was using `this.` inside its function body was enough for other to say no.

Comment: The litmus test for purity is "it shouldn't cause observable side-effects and it should work the same each invocation". The method fulfils both. Then again, I am not sure why that would matter that much. *So what* if it's pure? Or impure?

Comment: In addition to *VLAZ*' statement ... let's consider we deal with pure **functions** only. Now the functions are *nailed* to a namespace (other than the global object, ... let's say a module) which technically makes them _"pure methods"_.  Now, what is the advantage of implementing such methods which do neither access nor compute/mutate any `this` context as non/prototypal (and/or static) class methods in comparison to the module implementation?

Comment: Given that Javascript is very mutable, a pure function may suddenly be replaced with an impure one at runtime for whatever bizarre reasons… So… what's the distinction *really* useful for then? This isn't Haskell, where it makes an actual difference to the compiler.

Comment: @PeterSeliger `this` isn't really special. It can be treated as an argument to the function. Because it is. Especially if you use `.call()` or `.apply()` where you actually pass it in as argument. And a pure function should produce the same result given the same arguments - whether you do `getProp({name: "Fred"}, "name")` (which returns `"Fred"`) or `getProp.call({name: "Fred"}, "name")` the result is the same. It's referentially transparent, too: first might be implemented as `obj[prop]` the second as `this[prop]` but both can be substituted with `({name: "Fred"})["name"]`.

Comment: @deceze Purity is not just a tool for the compiler, but an aid in reasoning about and understanding how a function works. And people ignore bizarre edge cases for that.

Comment: "*the the fact, that `MethodA` was using `this.` inside its function body was enough for other to say no*" - they're wrong. Only if `this` is mutated (its properties are written to), the function is no longer pure.

Comment: @VLAZ ... I'm aware of that. But then one could pass such data (what was the `this` context) as a normal object to pure functions. I'm not against pure methods, I was just questioning the approach of implementing pure functionality with classes as shown by the OP. If there was a plausible answer/reason to it, nothing prevents the OP continuing with this path. If not, the OP should use a simple module based approach.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for this interesting thread :)
We concluded internally, that since we are working with javaScript it doesn't make make sense to argue purity for purities sake.
So as long as not side effects/mutations are being caused and the result is deterministic, it's pure.

Comment: "*So as long as not side effects/mutations are being caused and the result is deterministic, it's pure.*" that's the usual definition of purity.